# Create CSV file from a text file with header tokens using shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, csv, text, scripting

I want to create a CSV file from a bunch of text files in a directory with the following structure to import them into a database later.

```
Title:
Article title

Word Count:
100

Summary:
Article summary.

Can consist of multiple lines.
    
Keywords:
keyword1, keyword2, keyword3


Article Body:
The rest of the article body.

Till the end of the file.
```

So desired result is to have them in a CSV file with sections as headers with their contents as follows.

```
Title          | Word Count | Summary                  | Keywords                     | Article Body |
Article title  | 100        | Article summary.\nCan... | keyword1, keyword2, keyword3 | ...          |
Article2 title | 110        | Article summary.\nCan... | keyword1, keyword2, keyword3 | ...          |
```

I've tried a few approaches with awk and shell scripting but couldn't succeed so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Include expected output with the commands you tried

Comment: I've added expected output. I've extracted parts of a file using awk as follows but I'm looking for a more generic solution to create the whole file.


`awk -F: '/^Title:/{v=$2}/^Word Count:/{print v $2}'`

Comment: That doesn't look like CSV, though. The requirement to put comma-separated values inside some of the columns is decidedly weird, and surely hugely impractical. Perhaps a better design if I can guess what you ultimately want to accomplish would be to create two or three separate ouput files, with some sort of identifiers in each to allow you to map between them, sort of like in a relational database.

Comment: Like `1,Article title,100,Article summary ...,Article body` and separately `1001,keyword 1`, `1002,keyword two`, `1003,third keyword` etc and finally `1,1001` to indicate that article `1` contains keyword `1001`, `1,1002` etc. (I made the keywords 1000-based just to make it easier eo see which is which; in reality both could start from 1, or any arbitrary number really.)

Comment: The ultimate goal is to import the data into a PostgreSQL database. CSV would be practical cause PostgreSQL has support to import CSV files but could be something else that can be processed/imported as well.

Comment: does Postgre know how to handle csv files with commas as both delimiter and data? does the data need to be wrapped in double quotes and if so, what about embedded/escaped quotes? I'd suggest taking an example set of data (including commas and double quotes) and work out the actual file format that you'll be able to (successfullly) load into Postgres; once you have a valid format/structure for the file the rest should be (relatively) easy to figure out ...

Comment: most of the RDBMS products I've worked with have a method for loading tables from text files with a key piece of the puzzle being the user-defined field/column and record/row terminators (better tools allow for multi-character delimiters), eg, `###&&` as field/column delimiter and `%%%&&` as record/row terminator; net result: don't limit yourself to a 'simple' CSV format if the tool you're using allows for user-defined delimiters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html), PostgreSQL fully supports the CSV format, and a *Text* format which is compatible with the lossless [TSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) format.

Because I'm using `awk`, I choose to generate a TSV. The reason is that there are newlines in the data and POSIX awk doesn't allow having literal newlines in a user defined variable. A TSV doesn't have this problem because you have to replace the literal newlines with their C‑style notation `\n`.

Also, I changed the input format for making it easier to parse. The new rule is that one or more **empty line(s) delimit the records**, which means that you can't have empty lines in the content of `Summary` or `Article Body`; the work-around is to add a single space character, like I did in the example.

---

Input example:

```
Title:
Article title

Word Count:
100

Summary:
Article summary.
 
Can consist of multiple lines.

Keywords:
keyword1, keyword2, keyword3


Article Body:
The rest of the article body.
 
Till the end of the file.
```

---

And here's the `awk` command, which accepts multiple files as argument:

<sub>**edit:** added TSV escaping for the header / added basic comments / reduced code size</sub>

```sh
awk -v RS='' -v FS='^$' -v OFS='\t' '
    FNR == 1 { ++onr } # the current file number is our "output record number"
    /^[^:\n]+:/ {
        # lossless TSV escaping
        gsub(/\\/,"\\\\")
        gsub(/\n/,"\\n")
        gsub(/\r/,"\\r")
        gsub(/\t/,"\\t")

        # get the current field name
        id = substr($0,1,index($0,":")-1)

        # strip the first line (NOTE: the newline character is escaped)
        sub(/^(\\[^n]|[^\\])*\\n/,"")

        # save the data
        fields[id]           # keep track of the field names that we came across
        records[0,id] = id   # for the header line
        records[onr,id] = $0 # for the output record
    }
    END {
        # print the header (onr == 0) and the records (onr >= 1)
        for (i = 0; i <= onr; i++) {
            out = sep = ""
            for (id in fields) {
                out = out sep records[i,id]
                sep = OFS
            }
            print out
        }
    }
' *.txt
```

Then the output (I replaced all the literal tabs with `|` for better legibility):

```
Summary | Article Body | Word Count | Title | Keywords
Article summary.\n \nCan consist of multiple lines. | The rest of the article body.\n \nTill the end of the file. | 100 | Article title | keyword1, keyword2, keyword3
```

---

**Postscript:** Once you got a valid TSV file, you can use a tool like `mlr` to convert it to CSV, JSON, etc... but for the purpose of importing the data in postgreSQL, **it isn't required**.

The SQL statement will be this (**untested**):

```sql
COPY table_name FROM '/path/file.tsv' WITH HEADER;
```

<sup>**remark:** You don't need to specify the `FORMAT` and the `DELIMITER` because the defaults are already `text` and `\t`</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort @fravadona! I made some changes on your script and created an insert statement instead, thought that would be more practical. But I accepted your answer and I'll write my version as another answer. I just noticed the COPY statement btw, I guess you edited your answer. I'll try that as well. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome ;-) You can also do that, but the string literals will have to be escaped for SQL, otherwise a simple single quote in the data can break your `INSERT` statement

Comment: Yes thank you, that's what I was trying to do now :)

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes on @Fravadona's script and created an insert statement. Seemed more practical to me and it works. But the answer was really helpful, just adding here as a reference, might be useful for other people.

```
awk -v RS='' -v FS='^$' -v OFS='\t' '
    FNR == 1 { fn++ }
    /^[^:]+:/ {
        fieldName = substr($0,1,index($0,":")-1)

        sub("^[^:]+:[^\n]*\n","")
        gsub(/\\/,"\\\\")
        gsub(/\n/,"\\n")
        gsub(/\r/,"\\r")
        gsub(/\t/,"\\t")

        header[fieldName]
        record[fn,fieldName] = $0
    }
    END {
        ORS=""
        print "insert into article(summary, content, word_count, title, keywords) values(E\047"

        for (i = 1; i <= fn; i++) {
            sep = "\047,\047"
            out = ""
            for (fieldName in header) {
                out = out record[fn,fieldName] sep
            }
            print substr(out,0,length(out)-2)")"
        }
    }
' x.txt
```

Result:

```
insert into article(summary, content, word_count, title, keywords) values(E'Article summary.\n \nCan consist of multiple lines.','The rest of the article body.\n \nTill the end of the file.','100','Article title','keyword1, keyword2, keyword3')
```